# Null Pointer Exception for ArrayList in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I keep getting a null pointer exception for my array list.  I don't understand why it's throwing this error since the program is going inside of the if loop so that the bundle is not null.  I know the issue is in the line creating the arrayCourseList because following log.d is not printed.  Is my coding to retrieve the array list from a different activity just improperly called?  Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   Bundle courseInformation = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (courseInformation!=null) {

        Log.d("ErrorinActivity1:", "I'm in the if statement");

        ArrayList<String> arrayCourseList = courseInformation.getStringArrayList("courses");

        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayCourseList);
        ListView myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.courseList);
        myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        Log.d("ErrorinActivity1:", "I'm at the end of the if statement");
    }
    else {
        String[] courses = new String[1];
        courses[0] = "You must input a course before it can be listed";
        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, courses);
        ListView myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.courseList);
        myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
}
```

Here is the error log:

```html
07-09 11:31:36.275    6342-6342/? I/art﹕ Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
07-09 11:31:36.905    6342-6361/hssrp.courses D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
07-09 11:31:37.008    6342-6342/hssrp.courses D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb3eb3ec0, tid 6342
07-09 11:31:37.077    6342-6342/hssrp.courses D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
07-09 11:31:37.164    6342-6361/hssrp.courses D/﹕ HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb3fee0b0, tid 6361
07-09 11:31:37.221    6342-6354/hssrp.courses W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 10.312ms
07-09 11:31:37.225    6342-6361/hssrp.courses I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-09 11:31:37.283    6342-6361/hssrp.courses D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
07-09 11:31:37.305    6342-6361/hssrp.courses W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-09 11:31:37.305    6342-6361/hssrp.courses W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb3ff12a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-09 11:31:41.665    6342-6342/hssrp.courses W/art﹕ Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.internal.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
07-09 11:31:41.695    6342-6349/hssrp.courses W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 10.674ms
07-09 11:31:41.823    6342-6354/hssrp.courses I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1055(124KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 50% free, 1007KB/2031KB, paused 11.292ms total 107.367ms
07-09 11:31:41.841    6342-6361/hssrp.courses W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-09 11:31:41.841    6342-6361/hssrp.courses W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb3f8e700, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-09 11:31:41.864    6342-6354/hssrp.courses W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 40.660ms
07-09 11:31:42.298    6342-6349/hssrp.courses W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 83.393ms
07-09 11:31:43.110    6342-6361/hssrp.courses W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-09 11:31:43.110    6342-6361/hssrp.courses W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb3f8e700, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-09 11:31:45.909    6342-6349/hssrp.courses W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 22.607ms
07-09 11:31:50.346    6342-6349/hssrp.courses W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.836ms
07-09 11:31:51.990    6342-6342/hssrp.courses D/ErrorinActivity1:﹕ I'm in the if statement
07-09 11:31:51.990    6342-6342/hssrp.courses D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
07-09 11:31:51.991    6342-6342/hssrp.courses E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: hssrp.courses, PID: 6342
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hssrp.courses/hssrp.courses.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
            at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:487)
            at hssrp.courses.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at 

    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Here is the other activity from which the Array List is created:
   public class EnterCourseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enter_course);

    buttonClick();
}

public void buttonClick() {
    final CourseNameClass courseNameShared = new CourseNameClass(" ");

    Button enterAnotherButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enterAnotherButton);
    enterAnotherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText inputText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputCourseName);
            String courseNameString = inputText.getText().toString();
            courseNameShared.courseNameInClass = courseNameString;
            inputText.setText("");
        }
    });

    Button doneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doneButton);
    doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText inputText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputCourseName);
            String courseNameString = inputText.getText().toString();
            ArrayList<String> coursesArrayList = courseNameShared.getCoursesArrayList();
            coursesArrayList.add(courseNameString);

            Intent i = new Intent(EnterCourseActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            i.putStringArrayListExtra("course", coursesArrayList);

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

class CourseNameClass{
    String courseNameInClass;

    public CourseNameClass(String courseNameInClass){
        this.courseNameInClass = courseNameInClass;
        ArrayList<String> coursesArrayListInClass = new ArrayList<String>();
        coursesArrayListInClass.add(courseNameInClass);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getCoursesArrayList(){
        ArrayList<String> coursesArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        coursesArrayList.add(courseNameInClass);
        return coursesArrayList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is producing the error?

Comment: Have you initialized the ArrayList?

Comment: ArrayList<String> arrayCourseList = courseInformation.getStringArrayList("courses"); is the line throwing the error

Comment: where is the getStringArrayList(String foo) method?

Comment: Check and provide here as well the error log, to be sure that exception is where you are expecting...

Comment: i added the error and the other activity where the array is initalized

Comment: Try to use savedInstanceState instead getIntent().getExtras();

Comment: when i use savedInstanceState instead of getIntent().getExtras(); the courseInformation is null so the program runs the else statement instead of the if statement

Comment: I think exception is not at `ArrayList<String> arrayCourseList = courseInformation.getStringArrayList("courses");` but at `ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayCourseList);`

Comment: whenever I put a log.d after ArrayList<String> arrayCourseList = courseInformation.getStringArrayList("courses"); the error is thrown before the system prints the log.d

Comment: According to exeption message: your receive nullpointer on setAdapter method...